# How to call a function from the function prototyping from

Tags: javascript

trying to understand how the prototyping works in JS. I know every instance created from the constructor function will have all the props of the function it is prototyping from. However, can I use props of the function I am prototyping from within that function. Example, is bellow. The problem is totyota.print and honda.print cannot access printName function. I know I can use classes for that but I would like to see if I can use functions instead to accomplish it

```
function Car(){
    return{
       printName:function(name){
            console.log(`this model is ${name}`)
    }
  }
}


function Toyota(){
  Car.call(this);
  return {
    print:function(){
        printName('toyota')
    }
  }
}

function Honda(){
  Car.call(this);
  return {
    print:function(){
        printName('honda')
    }
  }
}

var toyota = new Toyota();
var honda = new Honda();
toyota.print()
honda.print()
```

Comment: when you say props you are referring to `arguments` right?

Comment: refer to MDN for prototype documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not seen the pattern you are following. Usually, when trying to implement inheritance with the Constructor function, the `prototype` property is used.

What happens (simplified) when you call a constcuctor, method with `new` is:

```
 function Car(){
//implicitly a new this object is created
//You assign properties here
//this is returned implicilty
    }
```

In your code, you are returning your own object, using the `return` keyword. But there are a few points missing:

1. When functions (except arrow) run, `this` depends on the object on which function is called. The instance before `.`. If that is missing it is the global object. `printName()` will be called in the global context.
2. The Car constructor is called but not made use of. The object returned is not used.

But if I have to modify your code I would do something like this:

```js
function Car(){
    return{
       printName:function(name){
            console.log(`this model is ${name}`)
    }
  }
}


function Toyota(){
  const newCar = Car.call(this);
  return { 
 ...newCar,
print:function(){

        this.printName('toyota');
    }
  }
}

function Honda(){
 const newCar = Car.call(this);
  return {
   ...newCar,
    print:function(){
        this.printName('honda')
    }
  }
}

var toyota = new Toyota();
var honda = new Honda();
toyota.print()
honda.print()
```

The above code solves both the issues:

1. `printName()` is called on `this`. `this` when `print()` runs is `toyota` instance or `honda` instance.
2. The object returned from `Car` is used in the object that is returned.

Comment: thank you, that solved my problem.Yyou mentioned that you never seen pattern like that, you are probably correct.I am coming from OOP and trying to shift my mindset to functional programming.I can do what I intended with classe-ssnippet bellow but want to learn to do the same in JS without classes 
```
class Car{
 printName(name){console.log(`this model is ${name}`)}
}
class Toyota extends Car{
 print(){super.printName('toyota');}
}
class Honda extends Car{
 print(){super.printName('honda')}
}
var toyota = new Toyota();
var honda = new Honda();
toyota.print()
honda.print()
 ```